# Google Sheets: sum two columns by QUERY with some empty cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have try to get sum of two columns using `query` function in Google Sheets.

```
  Col1   Col2    Col3
  -----------------------
  12             User1
  23     44      creature
         55      User1
  14             User1
```

This work fine if there are at least one number in each column:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE('SomeURL';"Page!A1:C");
"select (sum(Col1) + sum(Col2)) where Col3 = 'User1'")
```

However this query cause error `QUERY:AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC` if all cells in **one column** are empty in result set.

```
  Col1   Col2    Col3
  -----------------------
  12             User1
  23     44      creature
                 User1
  14             User1
```

How can I get sum of columns using `query` function, if sometimes the cells are empty in one of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(query(IMPORTRANGE("url","page!A1:C6"),"select Col1,Col2 where Col3 = 'User1'")))
```

This should work for a simple sum. But i don't think there's a way inside `QUERY` to consider blanks as zero or assume them as numbers. If you could actually import range into sheet(i.e., use them as helper columns), then you can use `ARRAYFORMULA(Query ({filter (A1:B6*1,NOT(ISEMAIL(A1:A6))),C1:C6}, "select *....`  You should convert blanks outside Query (by `*1`)or Sum them outside query. Or use a DOUBLE Query and double import range, which would be performance depreciative.

Comment: Just `sum(query)`

Answer (score 1):

You can SUM the Query, like this:
=sum(query('SomeURL';"Page!A1:C"); "select Col1, Col2 where Col3 ='User1'"))

OR use SUMIF() twice, once for each column.  It means 2 importranges, though, so it will probably be slower.